# Postgress vs MySQL: Commands out of sync;

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, transactions

MySQL scenario: 
When I execute "SELECT" queries in MySQL using multiple threads I get the following message: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now", I found that this is due to the limitation of having to wait "consume" the results to make another query.
C ++ example:

```
void DataProcAsyncWorker :: Execute ()
{
  std :: thread (& DataProcAsyncWorker :: Run, this) .join ();
}
void DataProcAsyncWorker :: Run () {
  sql :: PreparedStatement * prep_stmt = c-> con-> prepareStatement (query);
 ...
}
```

Important: 
I can't help using multiple threads per query (SELECT, INSERT, ETC) because the module I'm building that is being integrated with NodeJS "locks" the thread until the result is already obtained, for this reason I need to run in the background (new thread) and resolve the "promise" containing the result obtained from MySQL

Important: 
I am saving several "connections" [example: 10], and with each SQL call the function chooses a connection.
This is:
1. A connection pool that contains 10 established connections, Ex:

```
for (int i = 0; i <10; i ++) {
    Com * c = new Com;
    c-> id = i;
    c-> con = openConnection ();
    c-> con-> setSchema ("gateway");
    conns.push_back (c);
}
```

2. The problem occurs when executing> = 100 SELECT queries per second, I believe that even with the connection balance 100 connections per second is a high number and the connection "ex: conns.at (50)" is in process and was not consumed

**My question:**
A. Does PostgreSQL have this limitation as well? Or in PostgreSQL there is also such a limitation?

B. Which server using SQL commands is recommended for large SQL queries per second without the need to "open new connections", that is:
In a conns.at (0) connection I can execute (through 2 simultaneous threads) SELECT commands.

**Additional:** 
1. I can even create a larger number of connections in the pool, but when I simulate a number of queries per second greater than the number of pre-set connections I will get the error: "Commands out of sync", the the only solution I found was mutex, which is bad for performance

Comment: I don't think any supports it and seems a pretty bad idea because will be difficult to differenciate between transactions, plus you would need multiple threads per connection on the db side as well. Why can't you create two connections?

Comment: So, the problem is this, I can even create a larger number of connections in the pool, but when I simulate a number of queries per second greater than the number of pre-set connections I will get the error: "Commands out of sync", the the only solution I found was mutex, which is bad for performance.

Comment: Then you need to add more connections to the pool. Either you add more connections or you limit the number of parallel queries.

Comment: I read some solutions on the internet, and found "-> store_result ()" and "mysql_next_result", do you know how to call these functions using the jdbc c ++ connector?
I believe that there is no such function in the connector, for this reason I asked for an alternative solution in stackoverflow

Comment: What problem are you solving with this abstraction of executing a sql query?

Comment: I get the same error that appears in this post (link), this error can happen due to using the same connection to execute more than 1 (one) query.
For this reason I have to "wait" for the query to finish and only start a new query using the given connection in the pool if it "consumes".
Basically I have a pool with 12 mysql connections, when I run 100 select queries in separate threads the first 12 queries are successfully executed, and after 12 some X queries are also executed successfully, the problem occurs when a query is being made at a x loc pool whose connection has not been consumed

Comment: Example, let's say I have a pool with 2 connections only
Time 1:
 1 SELECT queries
 2 SELECT queries
Time 2: [the error can run here]
3 SELECT queries at the same time, because the first connection in the pool is "pending", the second connection in the pool is "pending", as I only have 2 connections in the pool, the third query is redirected to 1 connection that is also pending.

Comment: Store result will not help you, that's for getting results when you run multiple sql statements as a batch.

Comment: I need to do something to "wait" for the connection containing the SQL command within the thread to be consumed.
In other words: Do not limit the connection, but rather wait for the connection to be "consumed", do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I am currently doing the following:
sql :: PreparedStatement * prep stmt = c-> con-> prepareStatement ("SELECT * from test");
sql :: ResultSet * res = prep_stmt-> executeQuery();
c-> finished = true;

Comment: Is there no mysql command to check if the query has been consumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that PostgreSQL looks great with this (queue / queue), in a very efficient way, unlike MySQL where I need to call "_free_result", in PostgreSQL, I can run multiple queries on the same connection without receiving the error: "Commands out of sync ".

Note: I did the test using libpqxx (library for connection / queries to the PostgreSQL server in C) and it really worked like a wonder without giving me a headache.

Note: I don't know if it allows multi-thread execution or the execution is done synchronously on the server side for each connection, the only thing I know is that there is no such error in postgresql.